# Is there a wildcard to patch any sequence of characters between two characters?

Tags: diff, patch

I want to modify a patch that changes the checksum of a file

```
-SRCREV = "a43570ced29f21cfbd5eff12b843f9214271aaf3"
+SRCREV = "somechecksum"
```

to something else. Meanwhile the explicit checksum in the patch has changed in the actual file, the hunk is failing and I would have to generate a new patch, which can get a bit cumbersome.

So is there a way to replace anything in between the quotes or the whole line?

Comment: What OS environment will this run on?

Comment: It will run on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tell `diff` to use `ed` style output, the original text does not appear. However, there won't be any protection against corruption if you try to patch a file where the line to change has moved:

```sh
mkdir a b c t

cat <<'EOD' >a/test
1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
EOD

cat <<'EOD' >b/test
1. a
2. b
3 <<< changed!
4. d
5. e
EOD

cat <<'EOD' >c/test
1. a
2. b
4. d
3. c
5. e
EOD

diff -u a/test b/test >patch1

cp a/test t/test
patch -p1 t/test <patch1
cat t/test  # identical to b/test

cp c/test t/test
patch -p1 t/test <patch1
cat t/test  # correct line is changed

diff -e a/test b/test >patch2

cp a/test t/test
patch -p1 t/test <patch2
cat t/test  # identical to b/test

cp c/test t/test
patch -p1 t/test <patch2
cat t/test  # wrong line is changed - result is broken
```

---

If you don't have to use diff/patch, then a simple `sed` script might work. Something like:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\(SRCREV = \)"[^"]*"/\1"somechecksum"/' fileToPatch
```